# Notepad++ - how to find and replace using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find and replace in notepad++. For example I want to replace

```
border-radius: 2px 3px 2px;
```

I am using this code to find:

```
border-radius: ([^A-Za-z]*);
```

But my expression only search for this types of code (which have only one radius value):

```
border-radius:2px;
```

Please tell me how to find:

```
border-radius: **** ;
```

Comment: By first, one question mark would be enough. And by second - have you ever read about regexp syntax? All you need is to add repetition of your capturing group and a space.

Comment: too many question mark cuz stackoverflow does not allow comment below 14 letter. No I have'nt yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find `border-radius:` followed by anything, just relax your constraint:

```
border-radius:(.*?);
```

The `.` means any character. The `*` means any number of them. But the `?` limits that to minimum matches possible, meaning that it stops on the first `;` (otherwise the pattern would match whole line, were there multiple rules on the line).

Comment: I actually thought he wants to get the border radius values captured in separate capturing groups.